# Why multiprocessing is giving other results than regular functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, multiprocessing

I want to make learning process of my NN shorter, so that, I'm using multiprocessing. However, obtained results are wrong - network is not learning correctly (it is learning when using same functions but without multiprocessing). I have two problems. First - If I introduce some variable and use it inside the function realized with multiprocessing it works fine. The problem is that when I run the code and after that i change the variable manually (ex. >>>a+=10) the function inside multiprocessing don't see any changes. It runs as if varible is the same as at the begining. Second problem - after forcing 'fresh' data inside every time function is being run results are still incorrect. I have (other) problem that some of the initial weights and biases are too big or small and small change of their values don't affect the global result. So that, some of the output gradients should be 0, it is true in case of running the training without multiprocessing. When I use multiprocessing for training every gradient is different form 0 and they are not copies of one result. I'm running out of ideas what can be the problem and I need your help, please.

This is my code in which i run multiTrain():

```
def calcGradM(data):

    print(data[0])
    VC=-epsilon/score0
    for i in data:

        if i[2]==1:
            deltaMaskWB1[i[3]][0][i[4]]=i[0]*VC
            deltaMaskWB1[i[3]][1][i[4]]=i[1]*VC
        if i[2]==2:
            deltaMaskWB2[i[3]][0][i[4]]=i[0]*VC
            deltaMaskWB2[i[3]][1][i[4]]=i[1]*VC

def Grad(score0,lvl,layer,i):

    maskW1=np.zeros_like(wb1)
    maskW2=np.zeros_like(wb2)
    maskB1=np.zeros_like(wb1)
    maskB2=np.zeros_like(wb2)

    if layer==1:
        maskW1[lvl][0][i]=epsilon
        maskB1[lvl][1][i]=epsilon
    if layer==2:
        maskW2[lvl][0][i]=epsilon
        maskB2[lvl][1][i]=epsilon

    return([result(wb1+maskW1,wb2+maskW2)- 
score0,result(wb1+maskB1,wb2+maskB2)-score0,layer,lvl,i])

def result(L1,L2):
    ans=[]
    for i in range(pos1,pos2):
        ans.append(netResponse(L1,L2,i))
    return np.sum(ans)

def multiTrain():
    T0=time.time()
    global score0
    score0=result(wb1,wb2)
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
        for l in range(2):
            calcGradM(pool.map(partial(Grad,score0,l,2), range(hidLen)))
        for l in range(hidLen):
            calcGradM(pool.map(partial(Grad,score0,l,1), range(len(neuronsIn))))
        pool.close()
    print(time.time()-T0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables aren't implicitly shared in read-write between multiprocess parents and children.

Especially, if their values change in the parent, those won't be implicitly passed down to the children, or if the children change values, those won't be propagated to the other processes.

Children may (depending on the spawn mode) inherit the state of globals at the time of their forking off from the parent process, but you shouldn't rely on that.

There's a section about [sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) in the `multiprocessing` manual.

[This article](https://research.wmz.ninja/articles/2018/03/on-sharing-large-arrays-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing.html) might also help you.